# Pulling the images from the private app directory, select a few of those and send them to the next view

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am developing a camera app and whatever the pictures that i take using my app, those pictures should get stored in a **private app directory**.

If I click a button in the **1st** view, it should go to the **2nd** view showing the images retrieved from my **private app directory**.

I should be able to select a few of those images in the 2nd view and if I click the **next button**, the selected images should be displayed in the **3rd** view.

So, first of all, how to **create a private directory** and how to **retrieve images** from that directory?

And how to **select the images** and send them to the next view?

Also, I should be able to **change the order** of those **selected images** in the 3rd view

simply by **dragging them**. How to do this as well?

Comment: IN This Code, Instead of drawlines Add your ImageView/Image Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

If you are thinking to create an app for storing images & using the images in other app, then you are choosing a wrong path. Apple will not allow you to do that.

What you can do is you can store the images in your application provided directories.

For directories, you can follow these directories:

---

There are three kinds of writable paths to consider - the first is Documents, where you store things you want to keep and make available to the user through iTunes (as of 3.2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Secondly, and very similar to the Documents directory, there is the Library folder, where you store configuration files and writable databases that you also want to keep around, but you don't want the user to be able to mess with through iTunes:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Note that even though the user cannot see files in iTunes using a device older than 3.2 (the iPad), the NSLibraryDirectory constant has been available since iPhoneOS 2.0, and so can be used for builds targeting 3.0 (or even earlier if you are still doing that). Also the user will not be able to see anything unless you flag an app as allowing users to modify documents, so if you are using Documents today you are fine as long as you change location when updating for support of user documents.

Last there is a cache directory, where you can put images that you don't care exist for the long term or not (the phone may delete them at some point):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error;
if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

Note that you have to actually create the Caches directory there, so when writing you have to check and create every time! Kind of a pain, but that's how it is.

Then when you have a writable path, you just append a file name onto it like so:

```
NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeDirectory/SomeFile.txt"];
```

or

```
NSString *filePath =  [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeTmpFile.png"];
```

Use that path for reading or writing.

Note that you can make subdirectories in either of those writable paths, which one of the example string above is using (assuming one has been created).

If you are trying to write an image into the photo library, you cannot use file system calls to do this - instead, you have to have a UIImage in memory, and use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() function call defined by UIKit. You have no control over the destination format or compression levels, and cannot attach any EXIF in this way.

---

I Hope it helps you to fulfill your need & also make an understanding about directories.

Comment: Iam developing a camera app in which, once i install my app, it should create a private directory automatically. So, which one i have to follow among your suggestions?

Comment: The best will be to put them in libraries directory. We can also put them in documents directory, but that directory is used to upload the data to iCloud services by apple. So apple may question you on it. So best way to use is Libraries folder.

Comment: Do u know how to insert the images inside a vertical scroll view , to select a few of those images and to send them to the next view?

Comment: You need to add images into Scrollview an given frame. Set Scrollview content size to adjust all images. Add touch event for the view. get the touch event of object touched in touch Delegate method & then you can get the view, which is tapped. Then you can pass that view to next view.